# How to host some websites with a mail server (iRedAdmin)?

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config, mail-server, iredmail

I have installed iRedMail on my server and it is managing my emails perfectly.
I would like to use this server also as website server.
I went into the *nginx* config `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
`00-default-ssl.conf  00-default.conf`

when I add `www.mywebsite.com.conf`
it doesn't seem to be render.

mywebsite is not deploy, my nginx conf is simple.

Is it related to iRedAdmin config? since the file `00-default-ssl.conf` use the templates.
Does the templates in nginx override the conf file ?

Is there something I have missed on my conf ?

Thanks in advance !

content of   `00-default-ssl.conf`

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mail.mywebsite.com;

    root /var/www/html/iredmail;
    index index.php index.html;
    
    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/sogo.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/netdata.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/stub_status.tmpl;  
}
```

that is my conf for my `www.mywebsite.conf` :

```
server {
        root /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/public/;
        index index.html ;

        server_name site.mywebsite.com;

        location / {
                alias /var/www/blog/html/public;
                index index.html;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Nginx, create another .conf file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/site.mywebsite.com.conf` with the `server{}` block then symbol link the file to `sites-enabled/` folder.

use a different webroot folder from `/var/www/html` because in this one the `index.html` append `/mail` to the host

Comment: For some reason it worked on earlier Ubuntu 20.04 for files in sites-available to be named without a .conf suffix. But on Ubuntu 22.04 the nginx version seems to expect the files in sites-available to have a .conf suffix. When I added the .conf to my file, it magically worked again. Just leaving this here in case anyone else faces the problem